# Magento. Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id'

Tags: magento, join, collections

all. I'm trying to get all order items from database, where order status is not "canceled". Here is a piece of code:

```
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
$rents->getSelect()->join( array('sales_order'=>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item') . '.order_id = sales_order.entity_id', array('sales_order.state'));
$rents->addFilter('product_id', $productId);
$rents->addFilter('state', array('neq' => 'canceled'));
```

Dut, when i'm trying to run this code, i get an error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id' in 'on clause'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code to desire result, I have tried with one of the ordered product.

```
$items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
$items->getSelect()->join( array('sales_order'=>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order')), 'main_table.order_id = sales_order.entity_id', array('sales_order.state'));
$items->getSelect()->where('product_id=?', $productId);
$items->getSelect()->where('state!=?','canceled');
echo $items->getSelect();// will print sql query
print_r($items->getData()); // will print order into array format
```

Hope it will help!